# Can CFBundleVersion contain letters, and if so, how are they compared?

Tags: ios, versioning

According to Apple docs, the "Build" number, (aka `CFBundleVersion`) should be a "two-period-separated list of positive integers, as in 1.2.3". ([Source: App Distribution Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH28-SW18), section: Setting the Version Number and Build String) ([Another source: Info.plist reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-102364), section about  `CFBundleVersion`)

But, many released apps have build numbers with letters in them, for example, my version of Xcode is "6D570".

Apple docs also say that build numbers must increase for each binary you submit to the App Store.

So my question: can `CFBundleVersion` have letters? If yes, where is this documented, and how are the strings compared?

Comment: Wondering the same. Tried it with 2.0-beta-1  but we had some errors on the version when archiving. Although I'm not sure if it was related to the characters.